# https://dnsflagday.net/ report edns512tcp=timeout

Tags: server, dns, ubuntu-16.04, vesta

i have a Ubuntu 16.04.5 server with Vesta CP.
I checked the server on https://dnsflagday.net, and I got this report:

> domain.cl. @123.456.78.90 (ns1.domain.cl.): dns=ok edns=ok edns1=ok edns@512=ok ednsopt=ok edns1opt=ok do=ok ednsflags=ok docookie=ok edns512tcp=timeout optlist=ok
>
> domain.cl. @123.456.78.90 (ns2.domain.cl.): dns=ok edns=ok edns1=ok edns@512=ok ednsopt=ok edns1opt=ok do=ok ednsflags=ok docookie=ok edns512tcp=timeout optlist=ok

I do not know what **edns512tcp = timeout** means and I have not had much luck looking for a solution on internet.

Can someone help me? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that tool, any kind of "timeout" error is a problem, it means some server did not reply or the message (either query or reply) was eaten by some active element on the path, so it needs to be fixed.

`edns512tcp` is when the testing software does an EDNS query with a buffer of 512 bytes and over TCP.

If you go to `https://ednscomp.isc.org/ednscomp/` for your domain you will have the full test results.

For that specific error it is:

```
EDNS - over TCP Response (edns@512tcp)

dig +vc +nocookie +norec +noad +edns +dnssec +bufsize=512 dnskey zone @server
expect: NOERROR
expect: OPT record with version set to 0
See RFC5966 and See RFC6891
```

So you can see which DNS query was done with `dig`, that you can reproduce it (`+vc` is an old flag name that is an alias for `+tcp`). The test expects to get a NOERROR code back and an OPT record. Your servers did not reply at all, so the test failed.

It seems that your servers did not reply to that at all, which is wrong. Maybe they do not reply to TCP queries at all which is even more wrong. In all cases you will need to contact the entity responsible for maintaining those servers and point it to the test results so that they start to fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

thanks for your help.
I read more about it and I could detect that port 53 was being blocked by the firewall, I added the rule to the firewall to allow TCP connections on port 53.

Everything it's fine now

Comment: Thank you for this pithy summary which has enabled me to solve the same problem quickly.